# Rails Bootstrap modal box always displaying first record

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

I have a table of parent records. At the end of each row I have an icon popping a modal containing a fields_for for his children. But my modal is always displaying the fields_for of the first record on the table.

**_form.htm.erb**

```
<%= object.fields_for :categories do |category| %>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="form-inline">
              <%= category.input :name %>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
              <%= category.number_field :default_percentage %>
            </div>
          </td>

          <td></td>

          <td>
            <%= render 'product_fields', object: category, %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
```

**_product_fields.html.erb:**

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"></span>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><p align="center">Produits disponibles</p></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Actif</th>
            <th>Produit</th>
            <th>Prix forfaitaire</th>
            <th>Pourcentage</th>
            <th>Fixe</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <%= object.fields_for :products do |product| %>
            <tr>
              <td class="col-md-0">
                <%= product.input :active, input_html: { checked: true }, label: false %>
              </td>
              <td class="col-md-6">
                <%= product.input :name, label: false, readonly: true %>
              </td>
              <td class="col-md-2">
                <%= product.input :flat_fee, label: false %>
              </td>
              <td class="col-md-2">
                <%= product.input :percentage, label: false %>
              </td>
              <td class="col-md-2">
                <%= product.input :price, label: false %>
              </td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Annuler</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Valider</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea on how I can update my modal to display the correct fields_for ? (I'm very inexperienced in JQuery or JS and I feel like this the way to do it)

Thanks

**ANSWER:**

I have been able to have each row pop the same modal with a different content by specifying the target and id using an index like this:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<%= index %>">Modal</button>

        <div class="modal fade" id="<%= index %>" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Produits disponibles</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p> content of modal here </p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Case 1

- In HTML the `ID` of element should not be repeated.
  As you have mentioned here, you may have more popup with same `ID attribute`.

  - So either user same model or change id for each model.

Case 2

- The `object/locals` passing to `nested-attributes/partial` is same every time.

May you get the solution of the problem.

Comment: I'll probably pass an indexed object to the partial, it should do the trick but I'm not sure to understand about Case 1.

Comment: Do you have multiple bootstrap modal on same page?

Comment: There is only one modal yes but used multiple times. It is the same modal that I inject in each row of a dynamically created table.

Comment: If you are using same model multiple times then you must have to assign different id to each modal. 
Because as per the HTML attributes we can assign same `value/word/text` for class attribute but not in  id  attribute. If you assign different id to each modal I'm sure it will work.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I need to inject a different id at each use of the modal ? With ajax or jquery I presume

Comment: <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">  here you need to change id `myModal` to something else for each modal.

Comment: you can do one thing is attach `id` of record with modal id like `myModal1`, `myModal2` etc. and link should contain data-target="#myModal1".

Comment: In most of cases the axax we should prefer single modal for same functionality. As HTML parsing in browser is require time and space on page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144541/discussion-between-lrp-and-hiren-bhalani).

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky about ERB, when you're doing any looping you never want the ERB print tag, just the interpreter tag. I.e. you want to change this

```
<%= object.fields_for :categories do |category| %>
```

to this

```
<% object.fields_for :categories do |category| %>
```

Comment: Yeah but then my whole table disappear

Comment: ah apologies I was unfamiliar with the fields_for syntax. So you're saying only the first record in the products array is being displayed?

Comment: No Problem. And only the children of the first parent are being displayed. If I simplify the modal and only display the index from the fields_for, it always display 0.